# Is it possible to check the latency of internet connection to a of a remote location?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, internet, latency, cloud-computing

I plan to travel to a distant location and access a high performance computing system (located at where I currently am) while I have arrived at my destination then. However, I am worried about the internet latency of remote access causing problems in data transmission, so I hope to find a way to assess the internet latency of remotely accessing the system while I am still here to see if the latency is tolerable. Would it be possible for me to achieve this goal somehow?

Comment: `ping` does that, what exactly was the problem using it?

Comment: I think the issue OP has is wanting to test the latency FROM the remote location before they get there, rather than arrive and discover they're unable use remote access back to base. If you can get someone at the remote location to run the ping for you, that may be the only logistically possible way to do that before you get there. There are other ways you could so it, but they'd rely on getting things setup at the remote location first.

Comment: ´ping´ measures the RTT (round trip time), including both ways. When using TCP for RAS this is most likely the latency measurement you re looking for.

Comment: @KeithLangmead Well, the problem is that asking somebody to operate the supercomputing system for me is a violation of the state law